# How to Return Hours or Minutes from Django Annotation and F Expression

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model as give below:

```
class LeaveViewSet(viewsets.Model):
    def get_queryset(self):
        Leave.objects.annotate(duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('end_date') - F('start_date') + timedelta(days=1)
        ))

class Leave(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

But when I query on Leave and try to access the annotated field `duration` I get the `timedelta` object for example:

```
leave = Leave.objects.all().first()
leave.duration.days    # this gives duration in days
leave.duration         # this is how I want to get the value
```

I then added a property in the model as below:

```
class LeaveViewSet(viewsets.Model):
    def get_queryset(self):
        Leave.objects.annotate(leave_duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('end_date') - F('start_date') + timedelta(days=1)
        ))

class Leave(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    @propery
    def duratioin(self):
        return self.leave_duration.days
```

this way the serializer also work correctly and I can access `leave.duration` but want to know if I can get int type days instead of timedelta object in annotated field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`ExtractDay`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractDay) from the standard Django library:

```py
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay

# ...

def get_queryset(self):
    duration_expression = F('end_date') - F('start_date') + timedelta(days=1)
    duration_wrapper = ExpressionWrapper(duration_expression)
    duration_days = ExtractDay(duration_wrapper)

    return Leave.objects.annotate(leave_duration=duration_days)
```

Comment: Thanks @wencakisa, this really worked. I was looking for a way to use EXTRACT() from Django ORM and you gave the exact solution.

Comment: @MKJ I'm glad that I've helped. :)

Comment: can you please answer this one as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631679/how-to-combine-date-and-time-fields-into-datetime-field-in-django-f-expression?noredirect=1#comment99835150_56631679