# How to Combine Date and Time Fields into DateTime Field in Django F Expression

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have to get the difference of two `datetime` fields but one is pure datetime field and other is a combination of date and time.
I tried this one:

```
    qs = Foo.objects.filter(
        bar__baz_id=self.kwargs['baz_pk'],
    )
    start_datetime = ExpressionWrapper((F('x__date') + F('x__start')), output_field=DateTimeField())
    qs = qs.annotate(start_datetime=start_datetime)
    before_start_wrapper = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('start') - F('start_datetime'),   # 'start' is datetime field on Foo, start_datetime is annotated field on Foo
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
    before_start = Extract(before_start_wrapper, 'epoch')
    qs = qs.annotate(before_start=before_start/3600)
```

This also doesn't work;

```
    qs = Foo.objects.filter(
        bar__baz_id=self.kwargs['baz_pk'],
    )
    start_datetime = F('x__date') + F('x__start')

    before_start_wrapper = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('start') - F(start_datetime), # 'start' is datetime field on Foo, start_datetime is combined F expression
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
    before_start = Extract(before_start_wrapper, 'epoch')
    qs = qs.annotate(before_start=before_start/3600)
```

What django does is as follows:

```
...(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM "foo".came" - ("db_shift"."date" + "db_shift"."start")) AT TIME ZONE) /3600 AS ...
```

What I am expecting is:

```
...(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM "foo".came" - ("db_shift"."date" + "db_shift"."start")AT TIME ZONE)) / 3600 AS ...
```

Can some one please provide the solution with Django ORM? I know I can run a raw query but wanted to look if there is a way to do the same with Django ORM?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not use a `DateTimeField` in the other model?

Comment: no, but I have to make a big change, right now I want to handle it by combining date and time fields

Comment: @wencakisa can you please answer this one as well?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked around the issue and got the answer. Only need the `DurationField()` in the `output` param of the `ExpressionWrapper` instead of `DateTimeField()`. Here is the code:

```
qs = Foo.objects.filter(
    bar__baz_id=self.kwargs['baz_pk'],
)
start_datetime = F('x__date') + F('x__start')

before_start_wrapper = ExpressionWrapper(
    F('start') - F(start_datetime), # 'start' is datetime field on Foo, start_datetime is combined F expression
    output_field=DurationField()
)
before_start = Extract(before_start_wrapper, 'epoch')
qs = qs.annotate(before_start=before_start/3600)
```

This way I got to manage the issue I had earlier. This might be helpful for someone else.